# Запуск intellij idea на arch linux

Tags: java, linux, intellij-idea, archlinux

Установил intellij idea используя `yay` на monjaro kde. Установил sdkman и java.

При запуске с рабочего стола или `idea.sh` через проводник вылезает ошибка: `No JRE found. Please make sure $IDEA_JDK, $JDK_HOME, or $JAVA_HOME point to valid JRE installation`. Если же запускать файл `idea.sh` через консоль, то все стартует, при чем независимо от sudo. Как я понимаю, kde не может просмотреть текущие переменные окружения.

Вывод printenv:

`PATH=/home/egor/.sdkman/candidates/maven/current/bin:...`

`JAVA_HOME=/home/egor/.sdkman/candidates/java/current`

Чем можно такое вылечить?

Comment: пропишите эти переменные в `idea.sh`

Comment: Выглядит как костыль на самом деле? Может есть другое решение? Хочется чтобы скрипт запуска сам брал переменные, без из явного указания в скрипте

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После установки пакета `intellij-idea-ultimate-edition` необходимо установить пакет `intellij-idea-ultimate-edition-jre`.

Команда для установки:
`yay -S intellij-idea-ultimate-edition intellij-idea-ultimate-edition-jre`